# How to slice every element of a column of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I am trying to remove first and last 3 letters of all the values in a column. Please refer the following:

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | ABC12xyz |
| val2 | ABC13xyz |
| val2 | ABC14xyz |

I want the output as following:

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | 12 |
| val2 | 13 |
| val2 | 14 |

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
df['column 2'] = df['column 2'].str[3:-3]
```